# Perl catching STDERR and STDOUT of subprocess

Tags: shell, perl, stdout, system-calls, stderr

I have Perl script which is executing another script. How can I ensure that, when `CONNECTION.pl` is executed, I will capture STDERR and STDOUT,  so that I can put it in the log in the parent script? Bellow is the code from the parent script:

```
my $systemcmd ='perl bin/CONNECTION.pl "'.$expanded_sql.'" "'.$tmp_file.'" "'.$fetch.'"';

eval {
  my $rc = system($systemcmd );
};

if ($@) {
  $errmsg = $@;
  croak {message=>$errmsg};
  unlink $tmp_file;
}
```

Comment: `system` doesn't throw exceptions (unless you replaced it, for example, by using autodie), so that `eval` won't do much

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using [Capture::Tiny](http://p3rl.org/Capture::Tiny) to wrap the call to [system](http://p3rl.org/system).

Moreover, it might be cleaner to change the Perl script CONNECTION.pl into a module and [use](http://p3rl.org/use) it from your script rather than shelling out to call perl again.

Comment: You could avoid `system` (as you originally implied C::T would allow you to do) by using [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run). It's not as flexible as capturing output as C::T, but it is more flexible than C::T when it comes to running programs and interacting with them (including capturing their output).